# multiple stems in makefile rule

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I am trying to write a makefile that does something like the following:

```
%-foo-(k).out : %-foo-(k-1).out
    # do something, e.g.
    cat $< $@
```

i.e. there are files with arbitrary stems, then `-foo-`, then an integer, followed by `.out`.  Each file depends on the one with the same name, with integer one smaller.

For instance, if the file `blah/bleh-foo-1.out` exists, then

```
make blah/bleh-foo-2.out
```

would work.

I could do this with multiple stems if there were such a thing... what's another way to do this sort of thing in (gnu) make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to do something like this.  You basically have two options: you can use auto-generated makefiles, or you can use `$(eval ...)`.  To me auto-generated makefiles are easier, so here's a solution:

```
SOURCELIST = blah/bleh-foo-1.out

all:

-include generated.mk

generated.mk: Makefile
        for f in $(SOURCELIST); do \
            n=`echo "$$f" | sed -n 's/.*-\([0-9]*\)\.out$/\1/p'`; \
            echo "$${f%-foo-[0-9]*.out}-foo-`expr $$n + 1`.out: $$f ; cat $$< > $$@"; \
        done > $@
```

Comment: This is not too bad.  It does make me think i should be using something more flexible than make, though.

Comment: It could be.  I'll be interested to hear if you find something flexible enough to allow you to define arbitrary "pattern-like" rules that don't require explicit statements for each target/prerequisite, especially when the change involves a mathematical expression like "x-1" (if you're willing to list them explicitly then you can do this in make pretty trivially: it's only the requirement that a single generic rule be able to build all the target/prerequisite combinations which makes it tricky).