# Multiple stems on makefile target

Tags: regex, linux, makefile

Assume `ls` produces `a b c d` and I want to create files `a-b b-d c-b`, etc. To make `a-b`, I'd use a command such as `cat a b > a-b`, and similarly for the other ones. I wanted to use a `makefile`, but couldn't figure out how. I needed something such as:

```
FILES := a-b b-d c-b

$(FILES): %1-%2: %1 %2
     cat $^ > $@
```

Here `%1` and `%2` would be something like `\1` and `\2` in some regex notations. Is there any simple way to do this? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777612/multiple-stems-in-makefile-rule) answer, but it seemed to me too complicated and ugly for such a simple task. Maybe I'm asking too much, though.

Comment: There is no simple way to do that, no. There can only be a single placeholder ("stem") in a pattern rule. A simple loop over the targets would not be terribly complex, but probably overkill if your real need is just three targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777612/multiple-stems-in-makefile-rule), "You basically have two options: you can use auto-generated makefiles,or you can use $(eval ...).", here is the solution using auto-generated method,

```
FILE =a-b b-c c-d

all: $(FILE)

-include generated.mk

generated.mk: Makefile
        @for f in $(FILE); do \
                echo $$f: `echo $$f | sed 's/-/ /'`; \
                echo '\t'"@cat $$^ > $$"@; \
                echo ;\
        done > $@
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll do it this way then. By the way, why I have to use `echo "<command> > $$"@`? I tried `echo "<command> > $$@"` and the output was just `echo "<command> >`.

Comment: The shell variable `$@` contains the current script's arguments (you double the dollar sign in `make` to pass it through to the shell). The Make variable `$@` is the current target. But here, you want neither; you want the literal string `$@` to end up in the generated file. The quoting cleverly breaks the variable name apart in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

The following would seem to do what you are asking with a modicum of hassle.

```
FILES := a-b b-d c-b

$(foreach y,$(FILES),$(eval $y: $(subst -, ,$y)))

$(FILES): %:
    cat $^ >$@
```

I broke out the dependencies to keep this simple, but I imagine you could get exactly what you were asking for if you really wanted to,