# patch GNU makefile to support multiple stems

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Starting from the same problem discussed here: [Multiple stems on makefile target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092905/multiple-stems-on-makefile-target)

> Assume `ls` produces `a b c d` and I want to create files `a-b` `b-d` `c-b`,
> etc. To make `a-b`, I'd use a command such as `cat a b > a-b`, and
> similarly for the other ones. I wanted to use a makefile, but couldn't
> figure out how. I needed something such as:
>
> ```
> FILES := a-b b-d c-b
>
> $(FILES): %1-%2: %1 %2
>      cat $^ > $@
> ```
>
> Here `%1` and `%2` would be something like `\1` and `\2` in some regex notations.

How complex it would be improve the gnu-make code to allow such type of multiple stems?

I know that there are other workflow management system (like snakemake) that support this features, but I like very much gnu-make. This is the biggest issue I found.

Comment: The biggest issue is backward-compatibility.  How do you know whether `%1.foo` is supposed to match a stem of `%` and a suffix of `1.foo`, or a stem of `%1` and a suffix of `.foo`?  Beyond that there is a lot of code that assumes the "stem" is a single pointer plus a length, that would have to be figured out.  But that's just a matter of coding: the really difficult issue is backward-compatibility.

Comment: *"How complex it would be"* Probably more complex than coming up with some obscure `$(eval` + `$(shell` magic to work around the lack of this feature.

Comment: There is a good answer in the discussion you refer to, but the accepted one is most convoluted. That other good answer makes your question unnecessary, IMO.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-glob-matchstringpattern?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat can you elaborate a bit more your comment?

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly say that you want to stick to `GNU make`. Still, I'd like to post a solution using snakemake in case you find it appealing enough to change your mind:

```
SINGLE_FILES = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] # Or some code that generates this list

wildcard_constraints:
    # This prevents a, b, c, etc to be interpreted as regex
    file= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in SINGLE_FILES]),

rule all:
    input:
        ['a-b', 'b-d', 'c-b'],

rule ls:
    output:
        f= '{file}',
    shell:
        r"""
        touch {output.f}
        """

rule cat:
    input:
        # Assume output file names 'a-b', 'b-d' etc can be safely 
        # split at '-' to obtain the input pair of files
        ff= lambda wildcard: wildcards.cat.split('-'),
    output:
        cat= '{cat}',
    shell:
        r"""
        cat {input.ff} > {output.cat}
        """
```

Save as a file named `Snakemake` and execute as something like:

```
snakemake -p -j 1
```

I don't use GNU make but I think that for complex operations snakemake is a better solution.

Comment: Snakmake is for sure a good option. But I like very much the simplicity of GNU-make and i fill snakemake a bit verbose for the day-to-day use. The lack of multiple stem is the biggest issue of gnu make IMO